# ¿Cómo poner mas de una condición en un mismo if en C++?

Tags: c++

¿Se puede poner en un mismo if dos condiciones?
Algo como esto: if(y == -1 ; y == 1)

¿O tiene que ser si o si de esta manera?

```
if(y == 1)
   {   
        if(y == -1)
        {

        }
   }
```

Answer (score 7):

Encontré la respuesta.

Hay un tipo de operadores llamados "[Operadores Lógicos](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_logical)". Estos son:

- Negacion Lógica (NOT) `!a`
- Y Lógico (AND) `a && b`
- O Lógico (OR) `a || b`

El lenguaje también cuenta con las palabras `not`, `and` y `or` que se pueden usar para escribir las operaciones homónimas recién mencionadas. Por ejemplo `not a`, `a and b` y `a or b`.

---

El operador de negación indica que lo contrario a lo que esta dentro del if ejemplo:

```
if (!(a == 1))
```

Hace referencia a: "Si a es distinto de 1".

**Importante**: no confundir con el [operador de comparación](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_comparison) `!=` que casualmente permite escribir una expresión equivalente a la anterior:

```
if (a != 1)
```

El AND nos permite incluir varias condiciones dentro de un if ejemplo:

```
if(a == 1 && b == 2)
```

Hace referencia a: "Si a es igual a 1 **y** b es igual a 2". Es decir, todas las condiciones se deben complir.

Por último "or", es parecido a "and". La diferencia es que no es necesario que se cumplan todas las condiciones. Con que solo una  se cumpla es suficiente. Por ejemplo:

```
if(a == 1 || b == 2)
```

Hace referencia a: "Si a es igual a 1 **o** b es igual a 2".

Comment: ¿Puedes marcar la pregunta como respondida?